# Type mismatch error instr

Tags: vba, excel

I want to find the IC number in the policyowner(NRIC). But there is error in the code.

```
    Dim col As Long
    Dim IC, NRIC
    Dim name

    name = ActiveSheet.Cells(rw, 1).Value

    NRIC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("main").Columns(9)

    IC = InStr(1, name, "(" & NRIC & ")") <<<<< this is the problem (type mismatch error)

    MsgBox IC
```

The display:

**main sheet**

name column

- sherry

IC column

- S1233456c

**policydetails Sheet**

policyowner(NRIC) column

- sherry(S1233456c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[InStr Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instr.php) 3rd argument expects a string (*substring*).
You actually passed an array which is the entire Column(9).
For it to work, you need to loop through all the values in Column(9) like this:

```
Dim c As Range
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("main")
    For Each c In .Columns(9).CurrentRegion
        If InStr(1, name, c.Value2) <> 0 Then
            MsgBox c.Value2 ' I don't know what you want to do if you find the cell
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End With
```

An alternative would be to use the [`Find Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195730(v=office.11).aspx) of the Range Object.

```
Dim c As Range
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("main")
    Set c = .Columns(9).CurrentRegion.Find(What:=name, LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then MsgBox c.Value2
End With
```